# Can my Service Fabric StatefulService have both memory-only and disk-persisted data?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am designing a Service Fabric application that includes a stateful partitioned microservice. Some of the data must be persisted to disk however some related data is very ephemeral and I would like keep it only in memory. During a failover I do want the secondary instances to have the ephemeral data.

From what I can tell the StatefulService has only one StateManager and all collections created via that StateManager share the same behavior. In other words I can't have one reliable dictionary that is persisted to disk and a second reliable dictionary that is only in memory.

Is there any way to do this within a single StatefulService instance?

Answer (score 0):

No, Reliable Collections always persist all data to disk.

But if that related data can be generated on the fly from the data that's being inserted into a Reliable Collection, then you might be able to use [Reliable Collection notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-notifications) to generate that related data and keep it in memory whenever you perform an operation on a Reliable Collection. Those notifications are fired on primary and secondary replicas.

Comment: I believe the StatefulServiceDescription.HasPersistedState property allows you to control whether it is persisted to disk or not. I would like both behaviors in one StatefulService but I can design around this limitation.